# Excel get value from another sheet based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-conditions

[image]I have two sheets in Excel, Sheet1 and Sheet2. 
They both contain 3 columns A, B and C.

My goal is to get values from C in Sheet2 to C in Sheet1, based on conditions comparing the values in both A and B at the same time.

A in Sheet2 contains numbers grouped together, for example 11,11,13,13,12,12. A in Sheeet1 contains some of those numbers, but not nessecarily in the same order or the same number of rows, for example 11,11,12,13,13.

B in Sheet2 also contains numbers like 2,1,1,2,1,2. B in Sheet1 again contains part of those numbers. For example, 1,2,1,1,2.

There are only unique combinations of pairs in A and B (in that specific order) for Sheet1 and Sheet2 respectively.

C in Sheet2 consists of numbers connected to the specific combination of numbers in A and B.

Now, I want to fill C in Sheet1 based on the values from C in Sheet2. For example for C1: Get the value (row x) in 'Sheet2'!Cx, so that 'Sheet1'!A1='Sheet2'!Ax, AND 'Sheet1'!B1='Sheet2'!Bx (which would be the 2nd row in this example).

I was thinking about something like

```
C1=INDEX('Sheet2'!C:C;...)
```

where

```
...=IF(AND(MATCH(A1;'Sheet2'!A:A;0);MATCH(B1;'Sheet2'!B:B;0));?;?)
```

?= I don't know what I would write here, but I would want the return value of IF be the row number where both conditions are true.

The problem is that MATCH only returns the first number in A and B respectively for which the condition is true, while I have several non-unique numbers in A. I would want to look through the whole 'Sheet2'!A:A and get all the matching values, and then look through the corresponding 'Sheet2'!B:B to check the second condition.

Or there might be a completely different take on this problem. Do someone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to look at multiple values in a `MATCH()` function, example:

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

Formula in `C2` sheet1:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$6,MATCH(Sheet1!A2&Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6&Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,0)),"")}
```

*Note:* It's an array formula so enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This is how I normally do this. Will this work with concatenating numbers?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost, what exactly do you mean? e.g, concatenate `A1` and `B1` and match with just one column with the concatenated values?

Comment: in your example you concatenate a string and a number and match the result. OP wants to search for two numbers. What happens if he has 11 in Column A and 1 in Column B for one result and 1 in Column A and 11 in Column B. Will your solution still work?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost, I now know what you meant. And yes it would still work if you concatenate a `","` with it for example. Good point though!

Answer (score 0):

C1 Formula  `=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C;MATCH(A1;Sheet2!A:A;0);MATCH(B1;Sheet2!B:B;0))`